# Difference between not exists and except in sql

Tags: sql

```
Suppliers(sid: integer, sname: string, address: string)
Parts(pid: integer, pname: string, color: string)
Catalog(sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real)
```

Find the name of suppliers who supply every part?

```
select s.sname
from suppliers s
where NOT EXISTS (select p.pid
                  from parts p
                  where p.color='red' and
                        NOT EXISTS (select c.pid from parts p where c.pid=p.pid and c.sid=s.sid and p.color='red'
                                    )
                 )
```

Is this query correct?

Comment: Do you have the expected results? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following might be less confusing.

```
Select s.name
 from suppliers s
 join catalog c on c.sid = s.sid
 join parts p on p.pid = c.pid
WHERE Not Exists (Select p2.pid from parts p2 where p2.pid = c.pid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both NOT EXISTS and EXCEPT are condition functions.

NOT EXISTS prints a particular record or attribute value if the inner sub query doesn't return any row for that particular record.

For Example:

```
select c.sid
from catalog c
where NOT EXISTS (select *
                  from parts p
                  where p.color<>'red' and
                        p.pid=c.pid);
```

This query will return all the sid who only supply red parts.

---

Whereas EXCEPT behave as a difference operator which works same as we have studied in set theory.

For Example:

A-B returns all rows of A which are not there in B.